# Strange behavior of link fading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a "scroll to top" link for my personal webpage but I have ran into some strange behavior that I cannot seem to correct.

I want the link to fade in when the user scroll to a certain amount of pixels and then fade out again if the user scrolls up above this point. Pretty standard behavior.

The markup is pretty simple:

```
<a href="#home" id="scroll-top" class="scroll"></a>
```

The CSS:

```
#scroll-top {
    position: fixed;
    right:30px;
    bottom:30px;
    width: 30px;
    height:30px;
    color: #38555e;
    z-index: 99;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border:2px solid #38555e;
    text-align: center;
    background:#fff;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s linear;
    transition:all 0.2s linear;
    display:none;
}

#scroll-top:hover {
    background:#38555e;
    color:#fff;
    border-color:#fff;
}
```

and the Jquery code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        if(!( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )) {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('#scroll-top').fadeIn(2000);
            } else {
                $('#scroll-top').fadeOut(2000);
            }
        }
    });
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/chc91n5f/4/

My problem is that when the link is faded in, it waits about 2 seconds and then fades in fast instead of starting the fading immediately and fading slowly. Also when the link fades out it waits and then fades out fast.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Take all the `transition` out. Then it works. Double trouble in the house. http://jsfiddle.net/chc91n5f/5/.

Answer (score 0):

The fadeIn and fadeOut functions in jQuery are shorthands for animating the opacity.

jQuery animates properties as putting them inline and changing it untill it reaches a specific point. In your case it's changing the opacity to lets say 0.35677 and the browser animates this change.

In order to have a more sleek animation use CSS class (visible for instance) to modify the opacity.

```
body {
    height:2000px;
    background:red;
}
#scroll-top {
    position: fixed;
    right:30px;
    bottom:30px;
    width: 30px;
    height:30px;
    color: #38555e;
    z-index: 99;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border:2px solid #38555e;
    text-align: center;
    background:#fff;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s linear;
    transition:all 0.2s linear;
    opacity: 0;
}

#scroll-top:hover {
    background:#38555e;
    color:#fff;
    border-color:#fff;
}
#scroll-top.visible {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

And use the following code to change it:

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('#scroll-top').addClass('visible');
} else {
    $('#scroll-top').removeClass('visible');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in your scroll function..

In the most simple explanation.

When you scroll (1 tick with your scrollwheel) the code looks if you are past 100px. In most basic browsers and OS's the scrolling distance is 122px (correct me if i'm wrong). Problem is.. if you scroll 3 clicks with your mousewheel. you are 3 times past 100px and the animation of the fadeIn wil queue 3 times. At a certain point jQuery has enough of it and says you know what.. if you want the same long animation for a few times. i will skip a few times to spead my workload.

So much for the simple explanation.

You can disable this with a clearQueue (http://api.jquery.com/clearqueue/) and it will disable the flashing animation. edited like this

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
    if(!( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )) {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('#scroll-top').animate({opacity: 1},1000).clearQueue();
            console.log("test");
        } else {
            $('#scroll-top').animate({opacity: 0},1000);
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2uox7ep7/5/

Answer (score 0):

Its because it keeps on fading in/out as you scroll even when it is already fading and thus the delay. You can use a variable like `visible` to keep track of the visibility 
http://jsfiddle.net/chc91n5f/7/